# Does mongoose schema accept parameter

Tags: node.js, mongoose

First of all i don't know does this is possible but i am trying to pass param from here :

```
await new User(req.body, {lang: "lang"});
```

to fetch it here :

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: validationMessagesTranslation("name", "here fetch param")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose module, you can see something like this,

```
Model(doc?: any): any
values with which to create the document


Model constructor Provides the interface to MongoDB collections as well as creates document instances.

@event
error If listening to this event, it is emitted when a document was saved without passing a callback and an error occurred. If not listening, the event bubbles to the connection used to create this Model.

@event
index Emitted after Model#ensureIndexes completes. If an error occurred it is passed with the event.

@event
index-single-start Emitted when an individual index starts within Model#ensureIndexes. The fields and options being used to build the index are also passed with the event.

@event
index-single-done Emitted when an individual index finishes within Model#ensureIndexes. If an error occurred it is passed with the event. The fields, options, and index name are also passed.
```

---

But, you can set your parameters inside the object and do what you want with this parameters using *Mongoose Middleware*, like `schema.pre('save', fn)`. [Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) is the documentation page about middleware.

```
//### app.js ###
.
.
.
let object = { name: 'Daniel', lang: 'lang' };
let userMongooseObject = new User(object);
await userMongooseObject.save();
.
.
.

//### userModel.js ###
let userSchema = new Schema(...);
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    // do stuff
    next();
});
```

Comment: the UserSchema.pre("save") it gets executes after passing validation in schema i need something here: 

name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: validationMessagesTranslation("name", "here fetch param")
  }

Comment: I don't get what you want, sorry. Can you describe some more with detail please?

Comment: i want the param that i am passing here await new User(req.body, {lang: "lang"}); to fetch in mongoose schema here:
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: validationMessagesTranslation("name", "here fetch param")
  }
})
in required field i have a functions that returns error based on language param that i am passing but here i need to pass that param in order to get error message in the language that i want